# How can we select where to place a created menu

Tags: google-apps-script

I've just created a new menu in Google Script (Spreadsheet) but it place it on the end. Just after "HELP". Is there a way how to indicate where I want to put this menu?
[image]

Regards,
Rave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - AFAIK custom menus are always positioned after the Help menu.